# Maintain SameSite "Strict" Session Cookie Policy throughout redirect

Tags: php, security, session, cookies, session-cookies

Let's say you have a website `A`, of which you control the login + navigation across protected pages of `A` via PHP Session cookies. For thus maximum security, these cookies are all `secure`, `httponly`, and use `samesite` equal to `Strict`, and are limited to the domain of `A`, hence also "host-only".

If a user who's logged in now confirms a payment while on `A`, some banks / payment services will automatically redirect that user to execute a subsequent / multi-factor authentication on page `B` of the concerned service. After the client responded to that additional authentication, no matter if yes or no, the system normally redirects the client back to `A`.

What I'm wondering now is concerning security. Using the above-mentioned session cookie settings, the redirects to `B` and back to `A` would obviously cause that the client would lose the session, and get signed out after being redirected on `A`.

This can be avoided by setting the `SameSite` attribute of the session cookie to `Lax` in the server configs. However, what if I wanted to keep it to `Strict`?

The solution I came to think of, but no clue on how to implement this in PHP:

The session cookie configs on the server define the `Strict` value for the `sameSite` attribute, as I want that to be the case, in general. When the payment is confirmed on `A`, the function which handles that confirmation on the server-side, so before the redirect to `B`, changes that `samesite` value of the session cookie to `Lax`. Then, on the page which `B` redirects to, at the very beginning, I reset that value back to `Strict`.

Is something like this possible in PHP? Or would you rather consider sth like creating an entirely new session cookie having `Lax`, copy your `$_SESSION` data into it, and then take up that `$_SESSION` data back after the redirect, into the cookie you're using for the sessions on `A` using `sameSite="Strict"`?

Or any other, better-suited solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know payment providers usually require some kind of signed transaction token passed in the GET request. Such token is being sent back in the GET together with the redirections.

In such a case assign the session data to such a transaction token generated in the site A, send the token with the redirection to the the site B and restore the session data when the token is received with the redirect from site B.

The token must be signed, so site A and B must be sure that it originates from the site A.

This requires additional controls in place to prevent session hijack by someone who is in a possession of such token: some kind of additional session validation must be in place for example browser fingerprinting.

In such case there's no need to get the same session cookie.

Comment: Not sure if this rly answers my question; how do you pretend sending the tokenized data, an additional cookie shared for A - > B - > A or what?

Comment: This would be a parameter in a GET request, for example: `https://site-b.tld/transaction?transactionid=unique-transaction-id-for-example-UUID&token=signed-token`. Same params must be returned back after the redirection:  `https://site-a.tld/?transactionid=unique-transaction-id-for-example-UUID&token=signed-token`, and of course, the status of a transaction should be exchanged via API between both backends, without user's browser interaction (so called Instant Payment Notification). This is how it works nowadays.

Comment: Session data assigned to a token must be stored in the site A (for example in the database). Token must be validated by the site A before the session is restored.

Comment: Aight thx for that and I agree on the part of storing the session data related to the token in ```A```'s DB, but regarding the token itself, wouldn't it be wiser to store it on an additional http only, secure and samesite ```Lax``` cookie that [set in PHP] (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) before redirecting to ```B```? I'm just concerned of anything related to exposing tokens to js, as you do it here, for example. Then, upon return to ```A```, you can safely return checking the cookie you created, and delete it afterwards. Isn't that safer?

Comment: I mean I'm also not sure about the permissions the bank APIs give you to provide and send back additional ```$_GET``` s, and just suppose that I run into less trouble when doing that via a secured cookie whose lifetime is limited to the time of the authentication. Generally, docs discourage from sending session IDs across URLs, and sending an alias tied to session data is little different to me..? Would you still transfer the token across the URL, considering all of this?

Comment: I don't know API of the specific bank you want to cooperate with. For the cases I know, integration API requires such data to be sent back and forth. 

I understand your concerns about session security, that's why I mentioned the following additional security controls:  token validation before session is recovered,  matching session data with browser fingerprinting.

Additionally the session recovery by token should have short expiration time, i.e 5 minutes.

Comment: I feel like the best solution would be to 1) create a secure httponly cookie with samesite set to ```Lax```, storing a randomly generated ID, 2) generate additional CSRF token right after 1) and before redirecting to the authentication ```B``` (to verify that the cookie was indeed created on ```A```), and send that token via ```$_GET``` as you said, then 3) i) verify the origin of the secure cookie via CSRF token and its relation to the delivered transaction ID after redirect, and then ii) restore the session data via the cookies ID, then remove that cookie. How does that sound to you?

Comment: + client browser fingerprinting & lifetime of like 60 seconds for the additionally generated cookie, guess that sounds reasonable?