# How to properly restore a deleted PHP $_SESSION

Tags: php, session, session-cookies, session-variables, superglobals

So I have the following problem; I'm using a PHP $_SESSION to authenticate logged-in users and allow access to specific pages of a website `A`. As the protected parts of `A` allow to execute payments, its sessions have to be as secure as possible, hence I'm using:

- httponly
- hostonly
- samesite = Strict
- secure

PHP Session cookies.

My problem now is that, when a client triggers a payment to `A`, he gets redirected to his bank's page `B` for multi-factor authentication of the payment. After that, `B` redirects him back to `A`. Obviously, due to `samesite = Strict`, this process leads to the loss of the session cookie of `A`, hence to the loss of the client's session at `A`, so he / she will be automatically logged off after the redirect back from `B` to `A`.

Thanks to my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70723778/maintain-samesite-strict-session-cookie-policy-throughout-redirect/70725260?noredirect=1#comment125036962_70725260), I've been provided with a logic to restore the session safely, to not need to open the `samesite` attribute of my session cookies to `Lax`. All of this works fine, basically I successfully authenticate the client after the redirect back to `A` via a token. What I simply don't get is how you properly reset a PHP session. Basically, the steps I'm implementing are:

- Before the redirect from `A` to `B`, I store `json_encode($_SESSION)` on my server, together with a relationship to the authentication token, which will survive the redirect.
- After the redirect back from `B` to `A`, I authenticate the client and then retrieve the stored session data back using `$session_data = json_decode( $my_data, true )`.
- I then retry to restore the `$_SESSION` data using:

```
$_SESSION = $session_data;
session_commit();
```

When I do so, I tested out the following at the very start of the page of `A` to which `B`'s redirect points:

Test 1: `var_dump($_SESSION)` resulting in an empty array, which confirms that the session has been lost.

Test 2: `var_dump($_SESSION)` after doing the restorage procedure mentioned above. I get the `$_SESSION` data array, populated with the data I've expected. So far so good, the session data seems to be restored.

The problem now is that when I reload the page to which `B` redirect, without doing anything else, so together with the tests 1 + 2 again, I get exactly the same output, although the `$_SESSION` should already be populated when running the Test 1 on the second page load.

So it seems that my session data gets written into `$_SESSION`, but not saved such that it survives a page load. What am I missing?

Note that the session ID changes throughout the procedure I'm using to restore it as described above.

Comment: I don't understand what the difference is between the first redirect from `B` to `A` and the second reload of same redirect. In both cases you "restore" a new session and I expect the same results for test 1 and 2.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware The difference is that by Test 1 I mean that the contents of ```$_SESSION``` are checked before triggering the callback used to restore it as expained above. By Test 2 I mean that the contents of ```$_SESSION``` are checked after restoring it. Test 1 and Test 2 are both immediately executed on page load of let's say page ```A```, initially without session, as lost due to redirect. Load ```A``` once -> Test 1 should say it's empty, Test 2 should say it's populated, Load ```A``` again without redirect or whatever, just reload -> Test 1 should say it's populated. But it doesn't.

Comment: What if the redirect has a referrer in the header? In that case the session knows that you're being redirected back to `A`. You can check this in your developers tools of your browser.

Comment: Oooooh! So you're saying that the browser always re-deletes the samesite - session cookie if there's an external referrer in the header? And that that's the reason why it constantly re-generates the session data on every page (re)load after the redirect?

Comment: Well, I'm suggesting it, I don't know for sure.

Comment: hum that would actually make sense; well I can confirm that there's always an external referrer on the page reload. Question now is how to counteract the problem of a client who simply reloads the page after a successful redirect + authentication, because I obviously immediately delete the authentication from my server after it's being used. So when the client refreshes that page, it will automatically log him out, because the authentication token is not present anymore.. hmm.

Comment: I also think it makes sense. You can suppress the referrer in certain browsers, that would be the ultimate test to see if it is indeed this referrer that causes the session to be deleted.

Comment: I'll have a look. A workaround for that would may be to immediately redirect the client to the page ```A``` requested by the redirect, to get rid of the authentication token in the URL. Performance - wise that's pretty much okay I guess, as the session restorage is executed at the very start; so before anything of the page content is being loaded. But yeah, still 2 page loads, so not optimal. I'll check on the referer, thx already!

Comment: Indeed, the MDN docs say: ```Cookies will only be sent in a first-party context and not be sent along with requests initiated by third party websites.``` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite). Would indeed make sense. I can already kind of confirm your theory because if I reload the page after deleteing the ```?token?hgsja``` part of it, I get the ```$_SESSION``` to be populated after Test 1 already, as expected.

Comment: Yes, you could have an intermediate page, on site `A`, to return to site `A`, it restores the session and redirects to the normal page on site `A`. Only when that last page is reached you delete the stored session data from the database. This will work for a single reload, and if the user uses the back button they immediately get forwarded to the normal page on `A` again.

Comment: Interesting, now I also finally understand the reason why some payment authentication processes are followed by multiple redirects instead of just one. Crazy thx so much, I can't tell how much time I would have spent to figure out this problem!

Comment: Ok it's not the referrer, turned it off and same problem occurred. But your focus now made me focus on comparing the request headers coming from the redirect vs the request headers after deleting the URL params and then reloading, still checking..

Comment: Okay that was easy haha, there's exactly one difference in the request headers (when turning off referrer headers in Firefox): When loading the page from the redirect, the [Sec-Fetch-Site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Sec-Fetch-Site) header says ```cross-site```, and when reloading after deleting the URL params, it says ```none```. So I guess it makes absolute sense that what I described in my question was happening. Thx so much!

Comment: Sorry, I left for a moment. Good to see that you found out what the reason is. I had never heard of the `Sec-Fetch-Site` header, but it seems to have a function similar to what I though the referrer header would have.